# EFCore FromSql async

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I'd like to perform a couple of SELECT stored procedure calls in parallel.
I setup my context as follows:

```cs
public virtual DbSet<Task<GetCaseCaseContextModel>> CaseGetCaseContextData { get; set; }
```

My repo class then does the following:

```cs
public async Task<List<GetCaseNotesContextModel>> GetCaseNotes(string caseId)
{
    var notes = _context.CaseGetCaseContextData.FromSql("x_Fortellis_CaseGetCaseNotes @p0", caseId, caseId).ToListAsync();

    return notes;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Database.Repo.Case.GetCase.GetCaseCaseContextModel>>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Database.Repo.Case.GetCase.GetCaseNotesContextModel>'    CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Database  C:\Dev\Bitbucket\webscv\Fortellis\CaseManagement\CaseManagement.Infrustructure.Database\Repo\Case\GetCase\GetCaseRepoHelper.cs  72  Active

When I change the context to:

```cs
public virtual Task<DbSet<GetCaseCaseContextModel>> CaseGetCaseContextData { get; set; }
```

I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1061  'Task<DbSet>' does not contain a definition for 'FromSql' and no accessible extension method 'FromSql' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<DbSet>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Database  C:\Dev\Bitbucket\webscv\Fortellis\CaseManagement\CaseManagement.Infrustructure.Database\Repo\Case\GetCase\GetCaseRepoHelper.cs  70  Active

I'm ultimately want to call them using:

```cs
GetCaseCaseContextModel caseData = new GetCaseCaseContextModel();
List<GetCaseNotesContextModel> notes = new List<GetCaseNotesContextModel>();

Parallel.Invoke(
    async () => caseData = await GetCaseData(caseId, dealerGroupId),
    async () => notes = await GetCaseNotes(caseId)
);

return new GetCaseContextModel()
{
    CaseData = caseData,
    Notes = notes
};
```

Thanks
Alex

Comment: The context property should be `public virtual DbSet<GetCaseCaseContextModel> CaseGetCaseContextData { get; set; }` or `public virtual DbQuery<GetCaseCaseContextModel> CaseGetCaseContextData { get; set; }` , i.e. no `Task` inside. But you can't use EF context from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought, but could not find it in the documentation.

Comment: you forgot the `await` keyword before _context

Answer (score 11):

You have to rewrite with ToListAsync:

```cs
public async Task<List<GetCaseNotesContextModel>> GetCaseNotes(string caseId)
{
    var notes = await _context.CaseGetCaseContextData.FromSql("x_Fortellis_CaseGetCaseNotes @p0", caseId, caseId)
                         .ToListAsync();
    return notes;
}
```

Put `await`