# How can I call FirstOrDefault on FromSqlRaw asynchronously?

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

Related to: [EFCore FromSql async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267883/efcore-fromsql-async). With this async call:

```
public async Task<myClass> MyMethod(long paramId)
{
    return await _context.Set<myClass>()
        .FromSqlRaw("CALL myStore({0});", paramId)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync<myClass>();
}
```

I have this issue:

> `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated` was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated` method to perform the composition on the client side.'

so it seems that `FirstOrDefaultAsync` cannot be used with `FromSqlRaw`.

I tried with `AsAsyncEnumerable`:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<myClass> myResult = await _context.Set<myClass>()
    .FromSqlRaw("CALL myStore({0});", paramId)
    .AsAsyncEnumerable<myClass>();
```

but it fails to compile with:

> `IAsyncEnumerable<myClass>` does not contain a definition for
> 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method '`GetAwaiter`' accepting
> a first argument of type `IAsyncEnumerable<myClass>` could be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It should be a bit easier to understand now

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved it with this workaround because with `ToListAsync` it works.

```
public async Task<myClass> MyMethod(long paramId)
{
    List<myClass> myResult= await _context.Set<myClass>().FromSqlRaw("CALL myStore({0});", paramId).ToListAsync<myClass>();
    return myResult.FirstOrDefault();
}
```